# How to make exported variables reactive in a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a js file that exports a variable and increases it every second

```
let total = 0
setInterval(function() {
  total++
}, 1000)
export { total }
```

and a Vue component that prints said variable.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{ total }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {
    total,
  } from "./worker";
</script>
```

how can I make `total` reactive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible with value types because value types are passed by value (value is just copied). What you need is to pass a reference to an object...

`counter.js`

```js
let counter = {
  total: 0
};
setInterval(function() {
  counter.total++;
}, 1000);
export default counter;
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ counter.total }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import cnt from "@/counter";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      counter: cnt
    };
  }
};
</script>
```