# How to make a exported variable reactive in Vue 3 / Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I can't understand how I can make a exported variable from a script reactive in the template section.

I have [followed this Vue 2 stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502766/how-to-make-exported-variables-reactive-in-a-vue-component), but it doesn't work for me.

### Demo

Here is a simple demo on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-using-hooks-in-script-setup-g4pctr?file=components%2FMyComponent.vue

- script: `/assets/functions/test.js`
- component: `/components/myComponent.vue`

### Code

```js
// test.js
export let count = {
  total: 0,   // <-- make reactive in template
};

export const addCount = () => {
  count.total++;
};
```

```html
<script setup>
import { count, addCount } from '~/assets/functions/test';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const totalCount = ref(count);
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ totalCount }}</h1>
  <button @click="addCount()">Add+</button>
</template>
```

the `count.total`only updates after saving the vue-file / refresh the component.

### Question

Any suggestions how I can make a exported variable reactive in a clean Vue 3 / Nuxt 3 way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make it a react proxy using react system (`ref`, `shallowRef`, `reactive`, `shallowReactive`, `triggerRef`...)

```js
// test.js
import { reactive } from "vue"

export const count = reactive({
  total: 0,   // <-- make reactive in template
});

export const addCount = () => {
  count.total++;
};
```

```js
<script setup>
import { count, addCount } from '~/assets/functions/test';
import { computed } from 'vue';

const totalCount = computed(() => count.total)
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ totalCount }}</h1>
  <button @click="addCount()">Add+</button>
</template>
```

Comment: Note: this approach is problematic if you use (or later start using) SSR. Docs explicitly discuss this pattern: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#ssr-considerations